# Is there really a Mid 2014 13-inch Macbook Air?

Tags: macbook-pro

According to Apple's [How to identify your MacBook Air](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201862) guide and a search for [Macbook Air](http://support.apple.com/specs/#macbookair), they list only up to Macbook Air 13-inch, **Early 2014**. Similarly, so does [EveryMac.com](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook-air/specs/macbook-air-core-i5-1.4-13-early-2014-specs.html).

On the other hand, [Engadget](http://www.engadget.com/products/apple/macbook/air/13-inch-mid-2014/), [Maclife](http://www.maclife.com/article/reviews/review-macbook-air-mid2014), [PCPro UK](http://www.pcpro.co.uk/reviews/laptops/389437/apple-macbook-air-13in-mid-2014), [Macworld](http://www.macworld.com/product/1429030/13-inch-macbook-air-1-4ghz-128gb-mid-2014-.html), and [Apple Insider](http://appleinsider.com/articles/14/12/11/exclusive-deals-14-macs-at-lowest-prices-anywhere-up-to-150-off-macbook-airs-300-off-macbook-pros-200-off-imacs) all list the **Mid 2014** version of the 13-inch Macbook Air in their reviews.

So before I buy a Macbook Air, I'd like to be 100% sure: Is there really a Mid 2014, 13-inch version of the Macbook Air?

Comment: Given that it is nearly 2015, anything you buy new from Apple will be the latest version.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer here is yes, but the mid 2014 version was ONLY a processor bump. And most importantly the cpu bump was only in the two lower end models. Not the highest end i7.

Thus if you (like me) get the max spec cpu MacBook air, and click about this mac - it will say "mid 2013". If you get any other spec it will say 2014.

Confused? I was too!

Answer (score 0):

Last update of Macbook Air is [April 29 2014](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacBook_Air). I'm not sure if that's is Early 2014 or Mid 2014.

According to Apple and Wikipedia, it looks like Early 2014 to me.

Other sites may use the term Mid 2014 for the small spec boost update.